# Custom map in Mapbox Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I'm learning about Mapbox and want a custom map to look like a cartoon.
I hope everyone can help me and throw me some relevant documents.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Comment: i want to edit building, river, roads like toon

Comment: _"i want to edit building, river, roads like toon"_ - well I think that's just more _requirements._